# Can you get your fully filled map back if you lose it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I spent around one to two hours on a survival server trying to fill in a map (this is early game so I don't have an elytra yet).

I had just finished when I had a sudden urge to kill an enderman. I died and all of my stuff despawned before I managed to get it back.

Is there any way to get back the progress from the previous map without filling it in again by walking around? The server is on Java but supports Bedrock, which is what I am playing on.

Comment: This may be different with bedrock-java cross-play
Do check Radon8472's answer and see if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you made a [clone](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Map#Cloning) of that map, all your progress is lost.

An easy solution is asking another player to clone you a complete map.

Answer (score 3):

If you have admin permissions (or in singleplayer go to "open lan game" with "enabled cheats", you can use the command:

`/give @p filled_map{map:#}`

So e.g. if you lost the map with the number 20, type

`/give @p minecraft:filled_map{map:20} 1`

If you don't know the number of the map, go to you world-folder and take a look into the `data` directory, there will be files named e.g. `map_20.dat`.

Every file you see there was/is one map that somebody created on you map.
So you just need to try all existing numbers until you get the correct map.

**For the future I would advise you:** Always make a copy of important maps and keep in a safe place.

When one of the maps gets lost, you will see, that the map-copy will always have the same state like the "original" map (because the data of all maps with the same ID is stored in the same file in you savegame)

**EDIT:**

@Michael asked how the command for bedrock would be.
Unfortunally I can`t test it on bedrock, but according the [minecraft wiki article about the give command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/give#Examples), the syntax for bedrock is minimal different like this:

[image: /give command bedrock]

According this example I thing the correct bedrock syntax to get a filled map should be:

`/give @p minecraft:filled_map 1 0 {map:20}`

Comment: Can you do this in bedrock?  It doesn't like the "{" and it seems if I try e.g. "1 n" no matter what n I give it, it always gives me a map of where i'm currently at

Comment: @Michael I found something in minecraft wiki, that should work in bedrock, but I cant test it because I dont have bedrock edition. So it would be nice if you could leave a comment if that command works for you.

Comment: Thanks, I've previously tried this with the map key in quotes and got the error `Component 'map' was not an object.` and I think I tried without quotes and got a different error.  I'll try this again as soon as I get back.

Comment: When I try `/give @p minecraft:filled_map 1 0 {map:20}` I get this error:
`* Line 1, Column 2
Missing '}' or object member name`

Comment: @Michael do you play the latest version of minecraft ? The command Syntax changed from time to time, so maybe you have a different syntax, when you play an older version

Comment: Yes, latest version.

Comment: @Michael I am sorry, without the ability to test this by my own, I am at the end of my abilities.
According the wiki this syntax should be correct.

So either the information in wiki is incorrect or outdated, or this is a bug in bedrock.
Maybe you can write a bugreport at https://bugs.mojang.com/projects/MCPE